# Completable delete functions from DAO implementation produces IllegalStateException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Assume that we have simple DAO interface:

```
@Dao
interface MyDao {
    @Delete
    fun delete(entity: MyEntity): Completable
}
```

and we're expecting from Room that it will generate function which returns `Completable`. Execution of this `Completable` should delete entity from the database.

Now we call `delete` function in the main thread, but we subscribe to it in a background thread.

```
// Called in the main thread
myDao.delete(myEntity)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.background())
    .subscribe()
```

The problem is that this call results in `IllegalStateException` with such message:

```
Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

Interestingly, other functions like e.g. select (returns `Single<MyEntity>`) works perfectly, they can be created in the main thread, but they're executed in a background thread. So I looked into generated class to see which functions provides `IllegalStateException` in delete implementation:

```
public SupportSQLiteStatement acquire() {
    assertNotMainThread();
    return getStmt(mLock.compareAndSet(false, true));
}
```

The question is, is it a bug or should I call delete in a different way, like: `Completale.defer { myDao.delete(myEntity)) }`?

**Edit**

To be more specific: I'm using custom query for deletion (`"DELETE FROM myentities WHERE id = :id`) and here's generated code:

```
@Override
public Completable deleteByIdInternal(final long id) {
  final SupportSQLiteStatement _stmt = __preparedStmtOfDeleteByIdInternal.acquire();
  int _argIndex = 1;
  _stmt.bindLong(_argIndex, id);
  return Completable.fromCallable(new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
      __db.beginTransaction();
      try {
        _stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
        __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        return null;
      } finally {
        __db.endTransaction();
        __preparedStmtOfDeleteByIdInternal.release(_stmt);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that `acquire()` is called directly as part of `delete()`, instead of being called as part of executing the `Completable`?

Comment: Yes, see edited question, I pasted generated code.

Comment: This was [reported as a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123695593) a few weeks ago; a fix is supposed to be in `2.1.0-alpha05`. That version is out already -- is that what you are using?